# How can I prove $\sqrt{a^{2}}\le \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$ if $a^{2}\le a^{2}+b^{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, radicals, ordered-fields

Given that $$a^{2}\le a^{2}+b^{2},$$ how can I prove that $$\sqrt{a^{2}}\le \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$$ **strictly from the definition of an ordered field**? A derivation step by step would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$ are in the field. Note that $y-x=(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That works!

Comment: @Il-seobBae: Good!  Fine details depend on the string of little theorems one already has about order.

Comment: The statement in the title is not true: take $a=-2$ and $b=-1$.

Comment: @robjohn I've just re-corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume

$$\sqrt{a^2}>\sqrt{a^2+b^2}>0.$$

You can square every term without losing order and this implies

$$a^2>a^2+b^2$$ a contradiction.